# Turn off "The record source specified on this form does not exist" warning

Tags: vba, ms-access

how can I turn off/disable "The record source specified on this form does not exist" warning message? I created GUI that uses subforms, but the tables that are resource for these are generated in the process. So it means that GUI does not have any resource after opening the database and shows the error "The record source specified on this form does not exist". How can I turn it off/disable it? I tried to add `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`
but this has no effect on the error message.

Answer (score 2):

You could leave the *RecordSource* empty or assign it some (empty) dummy record.

When you set the *RecordSource* to its actual value, the subform will automatically requery.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at `Application.DisplayAlerts`

```
Sub Example()
'do stuff

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Code that fires the warning message
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'do stuff
End Sub
```

Comment: I am sorry, but this one gives me error that no method was found. On some other fora they mentioned that this is not available for Access.

Comment: My bad, I had missed the  [tag:ms-access] tag

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling alerts you can just assign some unrelated table to this form/subform.

Another solution - disable only this exact error if you have an error number (I guess it is 7874) like that:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
  If DataErr = 7874 Then
    Response = acDataErrContinue
  Else
    Response = acDataErrDisplay
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: well, I suppose it is the error 2580 and  the error-trapping does not work in this case.

Comment: Moerover, this does not qualify as an error, as it does not generate error number only the warning. However it does not respond to `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`.

Comment: I tried:    `Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
    Const conDuplicateKey = 2580
    If DataErr = conDuplicateKey Then
        Response = acDataErrContinue
    End If
End Sub` but to no avail.

Comment: @user9799161 you are right. Try to just leave RecordSource property empty in design mode as Gustav said.